# how to fix "not recognized as an internal or external command" issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

when i write a simple code like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

and start it without debugging it gives me this message

> '"C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\Debug\
>   ConsoleApplication6.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Press any key to continue . . .
>   <

can any one help?

note:I locked for it and the problem is not the "path"

Comment: Did you actually compile it? Is the executable in that location? (You'll need to choose "console application" when creating the project from scratch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+F7 only compiles the program. It doesn't build it. There are two stages needed to build a program, the compile stage and the link stage. Just press F7 instead of CTRL+F7 and try again.

Comment: no,I build it and run it but the same message comes.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"   Add this header file and try it.

Comment: yyyyyyyeeeeeeeeeesssssssss
but why it doesn't work on VS2012?

Comment: Because as you done changes to your project many times some of the defaults have changed....

Comment: how could i return it to default?

Comment: You can start a new project... Thats it it is simple.

Comment: Any other issues?